# How to add prefix to a controller in Phalcon PHP

Tags: php, url, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm working on a website using Phalcon PHP that has an admin section `mywebsite.com/admin`

I have created two different controller folders (`frontend-controllers` & `backend-controllers)` an depending on the URL, I'm loading the right folder.

I would like to add a prefix (`admin`) to the all backend controllers.

`mywebsite.com/admin/my-backend-controller-/myaction`

instead of

`mywebsite.com/my-backend-controller-/myaction`

I would like to know if it's possible and how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by using custom routes.

```
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
//Define a route
$router->add(
    "/admin/my-backend-controller-/myaction",
    array(
        "controller" => "my-backend-controller",
        "action"     => "myaction",
    )
);
```

Or make it general:

```
//Define a route
$router->add(
    "/admin/:controller/:action/:params",
    array(
        "controller" => 1,
        "action"     => 2,
        "params"     => 3,
    )
);
```

[More info in docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html)